# Piping grep matches into sed

Tags: bash

I have a file that might look like this:

```
EntryName1
1234
1234
1234
EntryName2

EntryName3
1234
1234
1234
[...]
```

I need to remove all entries that are followed by an empty line. I can grep the empty line and the repective entryName with `grep -E '^$' -B 1 myFile.txt`.

Now I would like to somehow pipe these as patterns into sed, in order to remove those lines from the file. How do I do that?

Edit: The expected output would look like this (leaving the blank line would also be okay).

```
EntryName1
1234
1234
1234
EntryName3
1234
1234
1234
[...]
```

Comment: Could you please show us the expected output?

Comment: Thanks, good idea. Edited the OP and added the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use awk.

```
awk '/^$/ { a = ""; next }
     { printf "%s", a; a = $0 ORS }
     END { printf "%s",a }' file
```

Answer (score 3):

A shorter `awk`:

```
awk 'p != "" && NF{print p} {p=$0} END{print p}' file
```

```
EntryName1
1234
1234
1234
EntryName3
1234
1234
1234
[...]
```

Comment: I should have pointed out that not all Entries actually start with 'Entry'. This was just a toy example. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

With `gawk` and multichar `RS` support:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\n[^\n]+\n\n"}1' file
```